# how to connect buttons in QT designer to python

Tags: python, qt-designer

so I have a line of code that I would like to connect to a button. I have it setup in QT designer and I have looked and tried everything but I cant get the file to import easily or get the button to run the code when pressed.
what I specificly want the button to do is to print a message into the window when pressed.

I have tried to import the UI file directly and I have tried to change the file then import but there would be some part of the pyside6 module that would not work or I couldnt get the button to do what I wanted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following are some commonly used ways to connect button and function.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        button = QPushButton("button")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        # method 1
        button.clicked.connect(self.press_func)

        # method 2
        # button.mousePressEvent = self.mouse_press_event

    def press_func(self):
        print("the button was pressed")

    def mouse_press_event(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        print("the button was pressed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I can't fully understand your question, would you mind providing more details on the issue?